# How can I find all lines of code I've written in a git repository

Tags: git

I'm trying to find out if I may have made a certain mistake in the past. I'd like to go throw all the lines of code in my git repo that blame to me and see if they have a certain characteristic that I'm looking for. So I figured I'd start with just trying to out put all the lines of code that blame to me. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Through the entire history?

Answer (score 5):

What about:

```
git log -p --all --author=your_name
```